# Concatenating in JSP/EL through a loop

Tags: java, jsp, el

So im trying to do something that might not be possible. I want to iterate through something like this:

i is set as an iterator

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="${total}" var="i">
   <td>${prod${i}.name}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

This Obviously doesnt work, but I think it portrays what im trying to do.

I want to concatenate a variable to another variable where i is what i want to concatenate to prod.name. Normally product name would be something like this ${prod1.name}. So i want to replace 1 with an iterator as it goes through the loop.

Im very new to JSP and EL type developer. So if im doing this completely wrong please tell me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done. My advice is to restructure your code so that `prod` is an array or a collection, then use c:forEach to iterate over its elements.

Comment: Thanks, I was kinda figuring that's what I would need to do

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (and most common way) to handle this kind of thing is to have your group of products be in a collection: e.g. you have a List of Product objects that is passed to the JSP, and then you do

```
<c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
   <td>${product.name}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was kinda figuring that's what I would need to do

Answer (score 0):

If the object's scope is known beforehand, then you can go around this by composing the key using [`<c:set>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/set.html) and grabbing the object directly from the scoped map using the brace notation. Here's an example assuming that `${prod1}` and so on is to be obtained from the **request** scope:

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="${total}" var="i">
   <c:set var="prod" value="prod${i}" />
   <td>${requestScope[prod].name}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

If it's in the **session** scope, use `${sessionScope[prod].name}` instead and for the **application** scope, use `${applicationScope[prod].name}` instead.

Regardless, this isn't the recommended approach. You should put a `List<Product>` in the scope and iterate over it the way as demonstrated by JacobM.

#### See also:

- [Beginning and intermediate level JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)
- [Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/01/hidden-features-of-jspservlet.html)